# Regedit Won't Start

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

I recently had an issue with a program not starting. I read the solution, which required modifying a registry key. When I went to start regedit I receive this message:

> The service did not respon to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Screenshot:

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

How do I resolve this problem?

Note: I am running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Which version of Windows?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have a read of the link. Then download the latest version of .NET Framework https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839174

Comment: Does `regedt32` work?

Comment: @DavidPostill - I wasn't even aware of `regedt32` but no, it won't launch either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `reg` command to access (and modify) the registry from the command line.

[Reg - Microsoft TechNet Library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx)

Note: Open the command prompt with administrative permissions to use `reg`.

Comment: @Lynda I think Steven means to say is to use the `reg` command to revert your changes to the registry _then_ see if opening it works again.

Comment: @Insane I believe she wanted to open regedit to make the changes not revert.

Comment: Oh. Well in that case your answer doesn't explain how to fix the issue. Just a work-around, using command prompt.

Comment: I saw the problem as "why won't regedit open" not "how to edit this registry key for the program that's not starting". I wouldn't ever think the 'program not starting' and 'regedit not opening' were related. But hey maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The solution to her program not starting was modifying the registry.  Since `regedit` won't work, I suggested `reg`.  Both are acceptable ways to access the registry.